# How to capture exception and/or logging when testing a click command with pytest's caplog?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-click

I'm starting with Python and in my first project I'm creating some clicks commands.

I've created an integration test that calls one of them and it was working ok. But suddenly it starts to finish quickly on Jenkins and passing ok. After doing some debugging I discovered that an exception is being raised, but it is not being captured by the test.

I read about the pytest's caplog fixture and tried to implement it but not luck.
Below is what I'm trying now. I already tried to inject caplog directly in the test function but it didn't work too.
Please, what am I missing ?

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def my_caplog(caplog: pytest.LogCaptureFixture) -> pytest.LogCaptureFixture:
  caplog.set_level(DEBUG)
  yield caplog

@pytest.mark.integration_test
def test_gen_using_click(my_caplog: pytest.LogCaptureFixture) -> None:

arguments = rf"""
    --log_file {output_test_dir}/gen.log
    """
runner = CliRunner(mix_stderr=False)
result = runner.invoke(bumps_gen, arguments)

assert result.exit_code == 0
assert len(my_caplog.records) > 0

for record in my_caplog.records:
    assert record.levelname != 'ERROR'
```